# Doing a map operation on the list class variable

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, ipython, jupyter-notebook

The code below returns an error:

```
class my_class:

def __init__(self):
    self.l = [(1,2),(3,4)]

def funct(self):
    self.l  = list(map(lambda x: x[0], l))
    print (l)

ob = my_class()
ob.funct()
```

> TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

However, if to separate the logic from the class - it works as expected

```
l = [(1,2),(3,4)]
l = list(map(lambda x: x[0], l))
print (l)
```

> [1, 3]

Could please anyone explain why doing the same operations on the class variable causes the aforementioned error?

P.S. I'm using python 3.4, although don't reckon it matters

Comment: This is my question and i've messed up the actual code, and this question is of no help to the community. Please remove it. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The code works if you actually use the attribute `self.l`:

```
    def funct(self):
        self.l  = list(map(lambda x: x[0], self.l))
        print(self.l)
```

Output:

```
[1, 3]
```

Somewhere you have a single int either in a `l` you have defined somewhere or in `self.l`, if l was not defined you would get  a `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'l' referenced before assignment.

Based on your comment that it is a typo then you have an `int` in `self.l` not just tuples:

```
class my_class:
    def __init__(self):
        self.l = [3,(1,2),(3,4)]

    def funct(self):
        l  = list(map(lambda x: x[0],self.l))
        print(self.l)
```

Then running the example:

```
In [2]: ob = my_class()

In [3]: ob.funct()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-e9ee341f0f31> in <module>()
----> 1 ob.funct()

<ipython-input-1-e1a6b2682f9f> in funct(self)
      4 
      5        def funct(self):
----> 6            l  = list(map(lambda x: x[0],self.l))
      7            print(self.l)

<ipython-input-1-e1a6b2682f9f> in <lambda>(x)
      4 
      5        def funct(self):
----> 6            l  = list(map(lambda x: x[0],self.l))
      7            print(self.l)

TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

`

Comment: Sorry for the typo. Yes you are right - that could work with that alteration, it means that there's something wrong with my main code. Could you please remove your answer so that i could delete my question?

Comment: @Dennis, if it is a typo, what is wrong is you have an `int`  somewhere in `self.l` not just tuples

Comment: Hold on, i'll try to post the real code in a sec

Comment: Padraic, thank you very much for your help!!!! It wasn't quite what you said , but eventually after the hundred times of looking in my code, i looked in it one more to post here and found the bloody error :) Thanks for your time and all the best

Comment: @Dennis, no worries,  you can answer your own question if you found a solution, just add the original code so it makes sense